# releasing NSURLConnection Object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsurlconnection

I have used the following code :

```
 NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if (theConnection) 
    {
        responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
```

in viewDidLoad method. But, I get a memory leak error on :

```
responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
```

How do I release theConnection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

receiveData is a class member,so I think release it in viewDidUnload is OK.

Comment: I have released it in ViewDidUnload but I get a  memory leak on :
responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
saying Potential memory leak on a object and stored in theConnection

Comment: @Moderator - You may please delete this post as it was duplicated by me. Sorry for the inconvenience